# Batch file to SSH Cisco phone and reboot it

Tags: perl, batch-file, ssh, cisco

First post, new to batch and scripting in general so please go easy on me.

I was tasked with writing a Perl script that would initiate SSH sessions with 6 phones and send them one CLI command to reboot them. Funny thing is, I know JACK about Perl. I do know a little batch automation and figured it'd be pretty simple to use plink to do what I needed. How wrong I was.

Here is an example of my plink batch.

```
@echo off
plink.exe -t -ssh XXXXXXX@111.111.1.1 -pw Abcd1234 < "C:\commands\commands.txt">output.txt
pause
```

Commands.txt:

```
debug

debug

reset hard
```

Running the batch file returns a cmd window displaying: Using Username "XXXXXXX"
And my output.txt shows:

```
debug



debug



reset hardsnoopyplus login:
```

It was at this point I realized I'd need some insight on how to service this second set of login credentials before sending my reset command.

Here we are at day 3 and my boss would like some results. I have about 4 broken iterations of my script and a good attitude. What can I try?

Also, here is a portion of a Perl script I found that claimed to be able to handle the snoopyplus debug login for cisco phones that I was unable to get working. The little bit of info I found told me to rewrite it in OpenSSH which I don't think is supported on Windows.

```
sub reboot{ 

my ($ip,$sshpassword,$sshusername,$debuglogin,$debugusername,$debugpassword,$debugprompt,$command) = @_;

print "\nPlease be patient whilst Cisco phone at address $ip is rebooted. This may take up to 90 seconds to complete...\n";  

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("111.111.1.1"); 

my $login_output = $ssh->login();

#my $ssh->login($sshusername, $sshpassword) || myAuditLog(LOG,"Login has failed. $!");

$ssh->waitfor('/'.$debuglogin.'>.*$/');
$ssh->send($debugusername);

$ssh->waitfor('/Password :.*$/');
$ssh->send($debugpassword);

$ssh->waitfor('/'.$debugprompt.'>.*$/');
$ssh->exec($command);

$ssh->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, take a look at [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2), which comes included with Strawberry Perl. Using it, you should be able to talk to your IP phones:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH2;

my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();

$ssh2->connect('example.com') or $ssh2->die_with_error;

if ($ssh2->auth_password($debuglogin, $debugpassword)) {
    my $chan = $ssh2->channel();
    $chan->shell();
    while (!$channel->eof) {
        if (my ($o, $e) = $channel->read2) {
            $out .= $o;
            $err .= $e;
        } else {
            $ssh2->die_with_error;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I looked at Net::SSH2 when I was researching Windows compatible alternatives to Net::SSH:Expect, but unfortunately with little to no knowledge of the language I'm afraid I'm lost looking at your code. I already have Strawberry Perl installed, and I'm taking some beginner courses to get my bearings. In the meantime I am still tinkering with batch files and Putty and praying I make a breakthrough!

Answer (score 0):

Try this format of plink command:

```
plink.exe -t -ssh -pw Abcd1234 -m "C:\commands\commands.txt" XXXXXXX@111.111.1.1 >output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After running that format, I get a flash of a cmd window before it closes, and the output.txt is blank. In previous iterations I couldn't make the "-m" work, it only ran when I used <

Comment: Try to delete output redirection `>output.txt` and add one more line with command `pause`

Comment: so something like: `@echo off

plink.exe -t -ssh -pw Abcd1234 -m "C:\commands\commands.txt" XXXXXXX@111.111.1.1

pause` (Forgive the edits I've never tried embedding code in a comment.)

Comment: the above code brings up a cmd window that already has the pause active. No indication it actually ran the commands.

Comment: So open your console window first, than type command and press enter? What happens now?